# iPad - CGContextShowTextAtPoint for multiline string

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-graphics, xcode4.5, cgaffinetransform

I am using following code snippet for drawing text:

```
CGFloat DegreesToRadiansText(CGFloat degrees) {return degrees * M_PI / 180;};
CGContextSelectFont (context, "Arial Rounded MT Bold", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (context, 0);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0);
CGAffineTransform myTextTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.f, -1.f ),(DegreesToRadiansText (-90));
CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, myTextTransform);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (context, 552, 445, "iPhone\nUser", 11);
```

Above code working fine if I draw single line text.

But if I add multiline text (i.e text having '\n' char as shown in above code.) it appears as a single line text.

Now I am getting output as shown in figure below:

http://tinyurl.com/crrz9ew

but I want output like shown in figure below:

http://tinyurl.com/ctntbfk

Is there any way with which I can draw multi-line string using function CGContextShowTextAtPoint Or Is there any alternative for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw it as CGContext's drawInRect:withAttributes method
where you must provide height for drawing text.